# Cerrar Excel desde código C#

Tags: c#, excel

Requiero cerrar un documento de excel que se encuentra abierto, no quiero que se cierren los demás excel que puedan estar abiertos, para abrir el excel lo hice con el siguiente código.

```
private void CargaDocumento_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ruta = string.Empty;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Lelo-Magdiel\Desktop";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx;*.xlsx";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ruta = openFileDialog.FileName;
        var proc=Process.Start(ruta);


        string coneccnioExcel = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source= "+ruta+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"";
        OleDbConnection conectorExcel = default(OleDbConnection);
        conectorExcel = new OleDbConnection(coneccnioExcel);
        conectorExcel.Open();


        //label1.Text = Convert.ToString (dt);
        OleDbCommand consulta = default(OleDbCommand);

        consulta = new OleDbCommand ("select Cedula,Nombre,Boleta,Patrono,Desde,Hasta,EBAIS,Medico,Diagnostico from [Hoja1$]",conectorExcel);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptadorExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adaptadorExcel.SelectCommand = consulta;

        DataSet miDataSet = new DataSet();
        adaptadorExcel.Fill(miDataSet);

        proc.Kill();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = miDataSet.Tables[0];
        conectorExcel.Close();
        int i = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        label1.Text =Convert.ToString(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lanzas el excel usando la clase `Process` entonces tienes control sobre esa aplicacion

```
var proc = Process.Start(ruta);
```

entonces podrias usar

```
proc.Kill();
```

para terminar con la aplicacion excel que iniciaste

[Process.Kill Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Si accedes al excel usando ado.net recuerda definir este en un bloque using

```
using(OleDbConnection conectorExcel = default(OleDbConnection)){

     //codigo

}
```

de esta forma se liberara el acceso al excel cuando salgas de esa seccion

Comment: parece que no toma el valor esperado  me lansa el siguiente error (System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

proc fue null.)

Comment: pero defines la variable "proc" en el mismo contexto? o sea lo que puse es un ejemplo, se supone que "proc" lo debes definir a nivel de clase si es que vas a realizar el cierre del excel desde algun evento

Comment: lo hago de la siguiente manera

Comment: Hice una respuesta a mi pregunta para poner lo que hice y que no me funcionó

Comment: no te deja editar la pregunta?, asi agregar el codigo

Answer (score 0):

El uso del proveedor Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0 es obsoleto, acá te dejo un ejemplo de código con el proveedor actualizado, cerrar el proceso de excel siempre ha sido un dolor de cabeza, con este código a mi me funciona bien.

```
string strConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";
            OleDbConnection radExcel = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [Hoja1$]", radExcel);
            dtExcel = new DataTable();
            adapExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
            radExcel = null;
            adapExcel = null;
```